# CSS remove horizontal scrolling when overflow set to hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a form that's broken into two sections. There is only one section visible at a time, the second section is animated in (using jQuery) after the user completes the first section and clicks next.

The way I have that setup in HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form>
        <div class="sections-container">
            <div class="section">...</div>
            <div class="section">...</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The CSS for that looks like this:

```
form {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sections-container {
    width: 200%;
}
.sections-container::after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
.section {
    float: left;
    width: 50%
}
```

When a user clicks "next", using jQuery, the `.sections-container` gets a negative `margin-left` applied to horizontally slide in the second form section.

The problem is in Chrome, when the dev tools are open with the mobile device view enabled, I can still scroll the page horizontally, though no scrollbar is visible. Why is this happening when I have `overflow` set to hidden, and how do I fix this so that the page cannot be scrolled?

Comment: are you using any framework like bootstrap ?

Comment: @Rupal I am only using jQuery and [JCF](https://github.com/w3co/jcf). But upon further inspection it looks like the horizontal scrolling is caused by jcf.radio.js from that JCF library so I think that's where I need to take a closer look. It's unfortunate that's the cause because that library takes care of a lot of work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the class period on the form CSS style. Should look like this.

```
form {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's actually a typo while I was writing the question. In my code, the form has a class and the CSS is properly targeting it as verified using the browser dev tools.

Comment: If your desired behavior is to advance the form to different inputs, I would either use a framework or use multiple section classes and hide the ones not being used using "display: none". When the user clicks "next" hide the current and show the next